# dumptrace file - /data/anr/

Tags: insufficient-memory, dumpsys

On Android Pie, everytime we take a bugreport, it generates a temporary file in data/anr. This temporary file is not cleared and stays on the device. Its size is around 2MB. This means everytime I take a bugreport on my device, the data/anr folder will have dumpstate_XXXX file that is taking up some space. How does Android clean this file and how often does it clean this file if at all? Else won't it cause my device to run out of memory eventually?

Comment: If an ANR occurs system cleans all files in `/data/anr/` older than a day: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#6230

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks for the pointer. I however have a device that has these data/anr/dumptrace_XXXX file staying there for more than a day. They don't seem to get cleaned up. Infact this file I have on my device is more than 15 days old.